# Github for Windows - Failed looking for HEAD error

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I've been using Github for Windows and Mac successfully for some time now but all of a sudden I get the following error.

> "Failed looking for HEAD in this repository"

In the repository details view after opening a repository of mine.

any help to clean this up would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this still happening? Where is the repository?

Comment: No, but I am not sure if this was corrected after the many Github application updates since this was posted? It was occurring on more than one of my repositories, https://github.com/trentmillar/snort-vc10

Comment: I am also encountering this issue.  It occurred after a recent GitHub for Windows update, and all of my repositories have the issue, even ones for which there have been no recent changes

Answer (score 0):

First, you must go into the repository that the error showed up in. Go ahead and close the notification and navigate to `Tools > Open A Shell Here`. Then the shell will then open for that repository. Now what we want to do is reset the merges that caused the error. You can do it with the following commands

```
$ git reset --merge
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
```

What we're doing here is we're telling GitHub to undo the merge that caused the error. Then, we switch from the detached head. Finally, we want to pull all the new changes we want.

Once you do that the error should disappear from that repository, and you shouldn't have any problems with it.

Comment: I tried this without success.  The three commands worked fine, but the Github app still complains "Failed looking for HEAD in this repository" when I try to select the repo with it.

Answer (score 0):

> The easiest way to resolve this would be to go into the repository that is saying '`failed looking for HEAD`', closing that pop-up, and clicking `Tools -> Open a Shell Here`.
>
> - From the shell, you can run '`git reset --merge`' to undo the merge that caused GitHub for Windows to crash.
> - From there, run '`git checkout master`' to switch from the detached `HEAD`.
> - After that, run '`git pull`' in the shell to pull down any new changes. It will prompt you to fix any merge conflicts (which is what caused the app to crash).

Once you fix the merge conflicts in the files, you should then be able to sync your code to github.